# making a setup file for a vb.net project

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-3.5, installation

I am making a project on VB.NET, after the completion of project, is it possible to install it in anyone's computer?

I mean to say, the project which I have made in VB.NET 2008, can be only run through Visual Studio,

I want this project or software to be installed in PC, with all databases and every file.

Is this possible?

Comment: You **build** your project, if its a windows forms project, look for `bin` folder and you'll find an `.exe` file.

Comment: @giddy Ya but that only works, when all files are together combined in a folder or how it was saved from VS. But I want something like how softwares are install, how to make a setup file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest option is a [Click Once Setup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71baz9ah.aspx). See [this walk through](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey.aspx).

If you want a slightly more customized installer you can create a [Setup Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx3b589t.aspx) then.

See this [older article on Setup Projects in VS 2005](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Win_App_Setup_Project.aspx). You'll get an idea.

Visual Studio setup will create an `msi` and an `exe`. There are also pre-ready bootstrappers for .NET framework, other installations. Meaning you can add, say, the .NET Framework in your installation and the installer will automatically check and install it on the target machine.

See this for [selecting Pre-Requisites for your setup.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eh4aaa5.aspx)

Lastly, it also comes with [Deployment Editors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zwt8xy2.aspx) that will allow you to place Files, Registry Keys or shortcuts on the target machine.

This isn't your only option, if you want a fully customized setup to do complex things, I'd suggest [nsis](/questions/tagged/nsis) (You'll have to write your whole setup in code)

Answer (score 0):

If you have only VB.NET 2008 Express, you can only make the ClickOnce. (Setup Project comes with Professional).

ClickOnce is not bad at all. User can run your Setup.exe on their own login, and simply ignore the “NOT TRUST” warning.

If you would like to make it looks better, you can make your Certificate file (free) in VB 2008. Project > YourApp Properties > Signing > Check Sign The ClickOnce Manifests > Create Test Certificate. Make sure you add the certification in Trusted Root Certification Authorities. You add it in you computer when publishing, and in user’s computer when installing. You can do this job in IE > Internet Options > Content > Certificates > Trusted Root Certification Authorities.

To buy a Certificate is very expensive though, and only the benifit is much greater than the cost, you buy it.